# How can we implement authorization server using the latest spring-security-oauth2 jars with Spring 5.0?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using spring-security-oauth2 jars from below location with Spring security 5.0:
http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/security/

The jars available there are:
spring-security-oauth2-core, spring-security-oauth2-client, spring-security-oauth2-jose, spring-security-oauth2-resource-server

I need to implement authorization server.

Earlier, I was using spring-security-oauth2 jar from the below location:
http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/security/oauth/spring-security-oauth2/2.0.9.RELEASE/

In the current version, various interfaces like TokenStore, ClientDetailsService, ClientRegistrationService are missing which were available earlier in oauth2 2.0.9.RELEASE.

Is there a way to implement the same using the latest spring-security-oauth2-core/client/jose/resource-server jars with spring security 5.0?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of the latest version (5.1.5), there's no native support for creating your own authorization server as there was with Spring Security OAuth, which had the handy `@EnableAuthorizationServer` and related support classes.

However, the good news is that it'll soon be supported by [Spring Security 5](https://spring.io/blog/2018/01/30/next-generation-oauth-2-0-support-with-spring-security):

> The plan is to also provide support for Resource Server by mid-2018 and Authorization Server by the end of 2018 or early 2019.

Apparently it'll be later in 2019 than expected.

Comment: The Spring Security team just announced that they no longer plan on adding authorization server support for Spring Security 5 https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/14/spring-security-oauth-2-0-roadmap-update#no-authorization-server-support.

Comment: They have backtracked on decision to not support Authorization server,  https://spring.io/blog/2018/01/30/next-generation-oauth-2-0-support-with-spring-security. spring-authorization-server is a [spring experimental project](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server). Spring security Oauth has been put on maintenance mode

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create authorization server using this [spring-security-oauth2-boot shim jar](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) until such time that spring security 5 rewrites this.